# Pass the checked status of CheckBoxes from rows of a ListView to another Activity on a Button click

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

**Problem**: After I checked multiple `CheckBoxes` that are displayed in a custom `ListView`, I still get back the whole row of data values shown in the custom `ListView` regardless of the selections I made. I guess the `CheckBox`'s status never changed at all after I checked them. So how to set the `CheckBox` status(true) after I checked multiple `CheckBoxes`? Furthermore, how to get the checked `CheckBoxes` positions from the `ListView` when I click a submit `Button`? Then, how to call `Model`'s class to retrieve the specific row of data including the `TextView` and `EditText`(for user to input) to be displayed in another custom list for checked `CheckBoxes` only?

**Summary**: I want to display array of row of values with **checked checkbox only** on another page.

testing1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="310dp"
        android:layout_x="0dp"
        android:layout_y="-4dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="293dp" >

            </ListView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="113dp"
        android:layout_y="346dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

testing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="208dp"
        android:layout_y="4dp"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="11dp"
        android:layout_y="15dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="22dp"
        android:layout_y="49dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="42dp"
        android:layout_y="89dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="35dp"
        android:layout_y="123dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="147dp"
        android:layout_y="13dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

MultipleSet1.java Class:

```
public class MultipleSet1 extends ListActivity
{


    List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.testing1, null);
            this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
         //final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         String temp = "Set_A";
         String response = null;
         ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", temp));

            try
            {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("PhPScripts", postParameters);
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to connect to server7777777777.", 3).show();
            }

            int size = 0;

            try
            {

             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
             size = jArray.length();

             for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
             {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                list.add(get(json_data.getString("description"), json_data.getString("price"), false));

             }

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail to connect to server7777777777.", 3).show();
            }

             ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveListViewAdapter(this, list);
             setListAdapter(adapter);

             Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    //@Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                        list = getListView();
                        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                        int size = list.getCount();
                        String checked = "";

                         String unchecked = "";
                         SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = list.getCheckedItemPositions();

                         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                         {

                             if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) 
                             {
                                 checked += list.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                             }
                             else  if(sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) 
                             {
                                 unchecked+= list.getItemAtPosition(i).toString() + "\n";
                             }


                         }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleSet.class);
                            intent.putExtra("TAG_DESCRIPTION", unchecked);

                            // Create the view using TabTour's LocalActivityManager
                            View view1 = bookingTab.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("BookingTab", intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                            .getDecorView();

                            // Again, replace the view
                            bookingTab.group.replaceView(view1);

                    }
             });




     }

     private Model get(String name, String score, boolean selected)
     {
         return new Model (name, score, selected);
     }

}
```

InteractiveListViewAdapter.java Class:

```
public class InteractiveListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model>
{
    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.testing, list);
        this.context = context;     
        this.list = list;   
    }

    static class ViewHolder
    {        
        protected TextView text; 
        protected CheckBox checkbox;        
        protected EditText scores;     
    }

    //@Override     
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {        
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {             
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater(); 

            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.testing, null); 

            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(); 
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.scores=(EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            viewHolder.scores.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {  
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {      
                    Model element=(Model)viewHolder.scores.getTag();
                    element.setScore(s.toString());        
                }    

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after)
                {       

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                { 

                }
           });         

            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);      
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked)
               {    
                   Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();  
                   element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());      
               }
            }); 

            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
            viewHolder.scores.setTag(list.get(position));
            view.setTag(viewHolder);   
        } 

        else 
        {
            view = convertView; 
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).scores.setTag(list.get(position)); 
        }                

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag(); 
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.scores.setText(list.get(position).getScore());    
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());    
        return view;

    }

}
```

Model.java Class:

```
public class Model
{
    private String name;
    private String score;
    private boolean selected;


    public Model(String name, String score, boolean selected)
    { 
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
        this.selected = selected;

    }

    public String getName()
    {  
        return name;     
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {    
        this.name = name;   

    }

    public boolean isSelected() 
    {     
        return selected;   
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {    
        this.selected = selected;   
    }

    public String getScore()
    {     
        return score;    
    }

    public void setScore(String score)
    { 
        this.score = score;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of problems:

- **Don't** use `AbsolutLayout`, that class is deprecated because you can't use it to make a layout that scales well on all the screens that the Android devices out there have.
- Don't put scrollable widgets(like a `ListView`) inside other scrollable widgets(like a `ScrollView`), this will not go down well.
- Don't do stuff on the main thread that could take a  long time to complete as you may end up with a "choppy" application or even worse the dreaded ANR dialog. This operations include any network operations, database access etc. Use threads or `AsyncTasks` to get the data from the internet.
- I'm not sure what you're doing with the `ActivityManager` but I get a feeling that is not something right. Just use the `Activity`'s `startActivity` method with an `Intent`.
- `getCheckedItemPositions` works with a default `ArrayAdapter` and one of the layouts from the SDK. If you make your own adapter with a custom row layout then you have to manage the `CheckBox` status yourself(and setup a way to retrieve that status). This part should be easy, there are thousands of questions and blogs on how to do this.
- The `getView` method of your adapter is incorrect. The tags should be set on the two views for each call of the `getView` method(so they should be set outside of that `if (convertView == null)` block). I also don't think those listeners will work pretty well.
- Even so, your code wouldn't have worked anyway because you set up an `Intent` with the data you need, but you don't actually use that `Intent` to start the new `Activity`  so you don't pass any information to the newly started `Activity`.

This should get you in the right direction.